# The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When Inserting a new Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting the following error when trying to insert a new entity and it's relationships via EF 6.1.1.

**NOTE**

I have lazy loading and proxy creation disabled.

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have meticulously checked all the navigation properties and they are all accounted for and not null.

I have also removed all the child entities from the object graph and I still get the same error. There are still FK relationships to other tables/entities but I can see that they all resolve. I.e. After calling AddObject but before SaveChanges I can see all the relationships have been resolved/hydrated based on the relevant FK Id. these are only lookups to existing data though.

So I don't understand what relationship is being set to null and or why

I have other entities that get saved just fine but this particular entity is not working.

What should I be looking for?

What more information, if any, should I provide to help explain the issue?

**EDIT 1**

Have turned logging on as per Steve's suggestion and this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#Log.Logging but the only statement that gets produced is Opened connection, I get no other statements produced when I call Save Changes. I have also run SQL Profiler and there are no statements produced here also!

**EDIT 2**

Here is the database diagram for the relevant tables. The primary table that I am trying to create a record for is the WorkOrders table. Users, RefList, Employees and ActivePolicies are only used for referential data is this context.

I set the FK properties by assigning the Id properties and not the navigation property.

It should insert data into **WorkOrders**, **WorkOrderEmployees**, **WorkOrderEmployeeArtifacts**, **WorkOrderEmployeePolicies** as well. Although if I do **NOT** add these to the **WorkOrders** entity and only create the **WorkOrders** entity with no children I still get the same error.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Pete

Comment: Check the generated SQL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks but no statements produced. EF must be doing some internal checking before saving? See edit above.

Comment: Hi @Pete, could you please show your database diagram and in which table you are trying to add data. How you assign foreign key relation while inserting?

Comment: @AbhilashPA. See edit 2

Comment: Hi @Pete, It is glad to see your database diagram. I have one more doubt. How **ActivePolicies** are related to your table **WorkOrders** ?

Comment: Are you creating any new entry to any other table while inserting data to your table **WorkOrders**?

Comment: @AbhilashPA **ActivePolicies** are related to the **WorkOrderEmployeePolicies** table via the **ActivePolicyId** property not directly to the **WorkOrders** table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91694/discussion-between-abhilash-p-a-and-pete).

Comment: @AbhilashPA I can't continue the discussion in chat as my employer has it blocked

Comment: ok, do you insert data to any other table while insert data to **WorkOrders**?

Comment: It should insert data into **WorkOrderEmployees**, **WorkOrderEmployeeArtifacts**, **WorkOrderEmployeePolicies** as well. Although if I do NOTadd these to the entity and only create the **WorkOrders** entity with no children I still get the same error

Comment: @Pete, table **WorkOrderEmployees** is a mapping table between **WorkOrders**  and **Employees**. But, you already have a reference of **Employee** in table **WorkOrders**.

Comment: @Pete, sorry to ask you more. What are the foreign keys in your table **WorkOrders**? Is all foreign key values are correct while insert? I know you have definitely checked these value. But, I didn't find any other issues in your db.

Comment: @AbhilashPA, true... but they serve completely different purposes in terms of how the data is described and related to each other. Also I am certain the values are correct

Comment: Looking at the diagram, are all the FK fields/columns  in tables other than `Users` named `Id`? Does `Id` also server as PK for the *sub*-object? 

That is confusing! 

I believe to clear up this issue, you should re-architect the tables to have named PKs which contain the table name such as `WorkOrdersID` and then have `UsersId` column as  FK. The only table with a PK named `UserId` should be the `User` table.

Comment: Setting an association can "steal" an entity away from another entity and thus nullify an existing foreign key. i think that's what happens here.

Comment: @GertArnold this is exactly what was happening just not to the entity I was thinking that it was happening on

Answer (score 2):

So in the end it was something else entirely that was attached to the context I was working with and nothing to do with the entities that I was trying to save.

How did I find this out?

In the end I thought I would remove all the relationships to and from the parent entity **WorkOrders** and then add them back one by one to see which one was broken... but as soon as I did this I still got the same error.

Digging deeper into the context I was using I found that I had a bunch of entities in the modifiedEntityStore and the same number of entities in the _entriesWithConceptualNulls. Looking at these entries made me realise that I had a logic error further up the code base when gathering the referential data required to save the **WorkOrders** entity.

Anyways... lesson learnt... make sure you check what else is in the EF context and is attempting to be saved.

Thanks for all the help

Pete

Answer (score 0):

> I set the FK properties by assigning the Id properties and not the navigation property.

Looking at the diagram, are all the FK fields/columns  in tables other than `Users` named `Id`? Does `Id` also server as PK for the *sub*-object/table?

That is confusing!

I believe to clear up this issue, you should re-architect the tables to have named PKs which are named such as `WorkOrdersID` and then have `UsersId` column as  FK.

---

Then set the navigation properties of the object *in full* before doing a save/submit. One should not have to worry about FKs ids directly. Once a save is done, EF will fill the values for the Ids due to having the navigation objects filled.